# What version of Ubuntu is right for my computer?

Tags: 11.10, distro-recommendation

I want to change operating systems from Windows XP to Ubuntu.

**System Info**
• Microsoft Windows XP Professional 2002 Service Pack 3
• Pentium 4 CPU 2.80GHz
• 5GB RAM

What is the best version of Ubuntu to install on my computer?

Comment: try Ubuntu on a live cd/usb and see what you think. it's your computer...

Answer (score 0):

Go for Lubuntu. It uses only 85 to 100 mb ram. You can even try Xubuntu it will provide more eye candy but higher ram usage.

Comment: You think ram is an issue with 5 gbs of it?

Comment: For 5GB of RAM go for Lubuntu 64-bits version. RAM is not the issue here but CPU.